# Log in console Gherkin steps with Robot Framework

Tags: console, robotframework, gherkin

I want to use Robot Framework to write and execute Test Cases in Gherkin format.
What I want is when I execute a Test Case, output in the console besides the name
of the Scenario, each step (When, Then...) and log as well if the step passes or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve such functionality with a listener that uses the [listener interface](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-interface) of the framework.

The [`end_keyword`](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-version-2) listener method will be invoked during execution when a keyword is finished. It will get the keyword `name` and its `attributes` as a parameter, so you can log both the name and the status.

You have to filter it so only keywords starting with `Given`, `When`, `Then` will be logged on the console.

Example:

```python
ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 2

def start_test(name, attributes):
    # Add an extra new line at the beginning of each test case to have everything aligned.
    print(f'\n')

def end_keyword(name, attributes):
    if name.startswith('Given') or name.startswith('When') or name.startswith('Then'):
        print(f'{name}    | {attributes["status"]} |')
```

Console output for the [behavior-driven development example](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#behavior-driven-development-example) of the user guide.

`robot --pythonpath . --listener listener.py test.robot`

```
==============================================================================
Test
==============================================================================
Add two numbers

Given I have Calculator open    | PASS |
.When I add 2 and 40    | PASS |
.Then result should be 42    | PASS |
Add two numbers                                                       | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Add negative numbers

Given I have Calculator open    | PASS |
.When I add 1 and -2    | PASS |
.Then result should be -1    | PASS |
Add negative numbers                                                  | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test                                                                  | PASS |
2 critical tests, 2 passed, 0 failed
2 tests total, 2 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
```